# Renaming abstract in amsbook

Tags: abstract, amsbook

I am writing my thesis and I am using the class `amsbook`.

I am using the `abstract` environment at the beginning of each chapter to make a short summary of the chapter itself. (I imagine this is not so good, right? But I like it. Do you have any suggestions in the case this is not typographically recommended?)

In any case, I was wondering how to rename the environment, so that instead of "Abstract" it appears something like "Summary of the chapter".

I have been trying using the command

```
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Summary of the chapter}
```

but it does not work. The output is always "Abstract."

EDIT: Here is an example of working code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twoside, reqno]{amsbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Thesis} 
\author{me}

\begin{document} 
\maketitle

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\begin{abstract}
   Abstract of the first chapter.
   \lipsum[1-2]

\end{abstract}

   \lipsum[1-2] 
\end{document}
```

which produces (a part from the title page) 
[image]

Comment: An example of code would be welcome. I get *no* output from `\chapter{Title}\begin{abstract}text\end{abstract}` other than the chapter title.

Comment: In amsbook the abstract is considered part of the \maketitle (like \author).  So basically what you want is an unnumbered section (like \section*}.

Comment: @egreg Added miminal working example and picture. Is it possible to change the word "Abstract" into something else? Thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `abstract` environment works just by chance.

I suggest to define your own environment, here identical to `abstract`, but customizable.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twoside, reqno]{amsbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{chaptersummary}{%
  \normalfont\Small
  \list{}{%
    \labelwidth\z@
    \leftmargin3pc
    \rightmargin\leftmargin
    \listparindent\normalparindent
    \itemindent\z@
    \parsep\z@ \@plus\p@
    \let\fullwidthdisplay\relax
  }%
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\scshape\chaptersummaryname.]%
}{%
  \endlist
}
\makeatother

\providecommand{\chaptersummaryname}{Summary of the chapter}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\chaptersummaryname}{Summary of the chapter}}
% maybe also \addto\captionsitalian{...}

\begin{document} 

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\begin{chaptersummary}
Abstract of the first chapter.
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{chaptersummary}

\lipsum[1-2] 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own `summary` environment, and format it with the `quoting` package/environment:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{quoting}
\newenvironment{summary}{%
\quotingsetup{font=small, leftmargin=2em, rightmargin=0pt, vskip=3ex } \centering{\bfseries Chapter summary}\vspace{-2ex}\quoting}{\endquoting}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Test Chapter}
\begin{summary}
\lipsum[1]
\end{summary}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
%Simple just use this!

\begin{center}
\textbf{Summary}\\
\vspace{0.2cm}
     This report will go over the functions blocks used in the Delta V Control Studio along with their mneumonics and short descriptions
\end{center}
```